# Arraylist to JSON string builder

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have an arraylist like:

```
List skus = new ArrayList();
```

and the output is

```
[{value=4, sequence=1, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846457, partnumber=602016000967318}, 
 {value=6, sequence=2, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846459, partnumber=602016000967319}, 
 {value=8, sequence=3, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846462, partnumber=602016000967320}, 
 {value=10, sequence=4, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846468, partnumber=602016000967321}, 
 {value=12, sequence=5, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846476, partnumber=602016000967322}, 
 {value=14, sequence=6, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846484, partnumber=602016000967323}, 
 {value=16, sequence=7, availableinventory=50, defining=size, skuid=24846492, partnumber=602016000967324}]
```

But i want to convert the above arraylist to JSON response which is a string builder like below .

```
StringBuilder jsonUIRespesponse = new StringBuilder();

[{"skuid":"24845337","value":"16","partnumber":"602016000967240","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"7","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845325","value":"6","partnumber":"602016000967235","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"2","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845326","value":"8","partnumber":"602016000967236","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"3","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845327","value":"10","partnumber":"602016000967237","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"4","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845328","value":"12","partnumber":"602016000967238","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"5","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845329","value":"14","partnumber":"602016000967239","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"6","defining":"size"},
{"skuid":"24845324","value":"4","partnumber":"602016000967234","availableinventory":"50","sequence":"1","defining":"size"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with a mapper that converts from Java Objects into JSON constructs. I use Jackson but there are other implementations.

First be sure you have Jackson library in your Java project. If you're using Maven you have to add a dependency. Just to be clear, AFAIK does not exist in JDK a common Json serializer/deserializer, so you must add a library in your project, i.e. a reference implementation of [JSR 353](https://jsonp.java.net/): Java API for JSON Processing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can convert Java Objects in Json with `ObjectMapper` utility class.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(skus);
```

or append to a `StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(mapper.writeValueAsString(skus));
```

Comment: I would want to append the sorted JSON values to jsonUIRespesponse (StringBuilder jsonUIRespesponse = new StringBuilder();) , So is there any other way without using Jackson. If so plz help

Comment: It is not clear how to sort json values. Your output example is not sorted. In any case, if you want a sorted json, I suggest to sort the java objects, I mean the values before the conversion.

Comment: Actually the sorted values are present in Arraylist "skus". So i just want to append the same order/values present in "skus" to stringbuilder "jsonUIRespesponse " , but i would want it as JSON format in  stringbuilder "jsonUIRespesponse " (with double quotes and colon).

Comment: the `writeValueAsString` method just converts the Java objects in json, returning a string with double quotes and colons. Have you tried it?

Comment: i Could not use that because the import function is throwing error ."com.fasterxml cannot be resolved ". So could you pls tell me how do i use ObjectMapper without the import statement?

Comment: You have this error because you have not added Jackson library in your project. I'll update my answer in order to give you a better overview.

Comment: If i am adding Jackson library then what will i have it inside the package package com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

public class ObjectMapper {

}

}

Comment: Is there any other way of doing thi swithout using Jackson library

Comment: No. Sorry, AFAIK does not exist in JDK a Json serializer/deserializer. I have again updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jackson Library.

```
  ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER    = new ObjectMapper();

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValue(stringWriter, YOUR_LIST);
    return stringWriter.toString();
```